# How to access the template function that is stored in the structure?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

```
struct taskinfo{
    template <class callable, class... arguments>
    taskinfo(callable&& f, arguments&&... args){
        std::function<typename std::result_of<callable(arguments...)>::type()> task(std::bind(std::forward<callable>(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...));
    }
};

void test2(int a)
{
    printf("%i\n", a);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    taskinfo t1(&test2,100);
    std::priority_queue<taskinfo> tasks;
    tasks.push(t1);
    //tasks.top(). Execute task
    return 0;
}
```

I need to execute tasks by popping out of priority queues.  My goal is to have a structure with function with any return type and accepting variable arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to access the template function that is stored in the structure?

There isn't a fuction stored in the `struct`.

When you write

```
template <class callable, class... arguments>
taskinfo(callable&& f, arguments&&... args){
    std::function<typename std::result_of<callable(arguments...)>::type()> task(std::bind(std::forward<callable>(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...));
}
```

you declare `task` as a variable **local** to the constructor.

Variable that is destroyed immediately after the end of the execution of the constructor.

If you want to store a `std::function` in the `struct`, you have to declare it as a member of the `struct`. But you need to know the type to declare it.

I mean... you surely can declare a template `struct` that contains a `std::function` with type dependent from the `struct` template parameters

```
template <typname R, typename ... Args>
struct taskinfo
 { 
   std::function<R(Args...>)  task;
   // ...
 };
```

but you can't declare a template (non static) member for a non not template `taskinfo`

```
struct taskinfo
 {
   template <typname R, typename ... Args> // <-- ERROR
   std::function<R(Args...)>  task;        // <-- ERROR 
   // ...
 }
```

Comment: can i have some kind of pointer to the function that is in constructor template, only store the pointer to the template function, where I specify the address of the template function within the constructor?

Comment: @raghu - sorry but isn't clear to me what do you mean.

Comment: @raghu - sorry but I didn't noticed the `std::bind`; the function do you want to store in the `taskinfo` struct is of fixed type? In the example (if I'm not wrong) is of type `std::function<void()>`; is **ever** of type `std::function<void()>` ?

Comment: @tobi303  - ehmm... "constructor"... thanks! Corrected.

Comment: no its not of fixed type thats why i am using `std::result_of`

Comment: @raghu - if isn't fixed, I don't think it's possible what do you want. You have to declare a struct that contains member of known type.

Comment: can u guide me how to do it if i restrict the callable return type to `void`. I am still unclear on that.

Comment: @raghu - the return type is a problem but isn't the only problem: do you need to know also the types of the arguments. If you give me a signature (by example: `std::function<void(int, long)>`) I suppose I can show how to bind a generic callable and some arguments to get a `std::function<void(int, long)>` and store it in the `struct`. But you need to fix (also with template parameter) the signature of the `std::function`.

Comment: @raghu - I've improved the answer; hope this helps.